# Geometric proof for Sophomore's dream

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, proof-writing

Is there a "visual proof" for [sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)?

$$\int_0^1 x^{-x}\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}.$$

In the wikipedia article there are two algebraic proofs, but the integral and the summation has a geometric interpretation. Because of that, I was thinking about it, that maybe there is a nice geometric proof for this statement.

Comment: what is the geometric interpretation, exactly?

Comment: I have yet to find a satisfactory visual representation of exponentiation with a real exponent. And that's just one of the ingredients here so the outlook is grim. It doesn't matter though! After a while algebraic statements portray as vivid a scenery as do other arguments.