A geometric interpretation of an algebraic equality
There is an peculiar algebraic equality:
$$\int_0^1\frac 1{x^x}\mathrm dx=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n^n}.$$
Some context.
The proof is relatively straightforward, one can write $\frac 1{x^x}=e^{-x\ln(x)}$ and use the exponential series $$e^{-x\ln(x)}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n!}(-x\ln(x))^n,$$ then apply a famous theorem to invert $\sum$ and $\int$...
The question.
My question is the following: is there a geometric interpretation of this equality?
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Edit. This question seems to have been already asked here but no answer was provided yet.

This has been asked (but not answered) before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298750/42969

@MartinR Thanks for the link, i will include it in the question. Maybe this new question will revive the interest for this seemingly open problem.

I think some application of here could be used to generate a geometric description - As $n$ goes to infinity, probably the error term for Euler-Maclaurin goes to $0$ which could be should shown geometrically
